# Avoiding Select in Excel VBA still doesn't speed up my code

Tags: vba, excel

This is the first time I couldn't find an answer to my problem on StackExchange. You guys are quite thorough. Anyway, we recently updated to Office 365/Excel 2016 from 2007, and now my VBA scripts won't run, except overnight. I researched and learned that I was a horrible person for using Select/Activate. I have seen the error of my ways, but now even simple code still doesn't want to run on a large sheet. My code, which clears the formatting from the current worksheet to make populating it with data faster:

```
Sub ClearFormattingAndValidation()

Dim referenceCell As Range
Dim rngToFormat As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set referenceCell = Cells.Find("Some specific text", after:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Set rngToFormat = Range(referenceCell.Offset(2, 0), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
'    rngToFormat.Select

With rngToFormat
    .Validation.Delete 'near-instantaneous
    .FormatConditions.Delete 'took 7-15 minutes on timed runs
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

When I uncomment `rngToFormat.Select`, I get a total of 76,302 cells, to give you an idea of the size of the spreadsheet. There is a LOT of validation and conditional formatting. In 2007, even using Select/Selection, it ran in seconds. Now, I have no idea how long it takes. I gave up after 5 minutes. It does run successfully on a smaller version of the worksheet.

I would like to avoid removing the validation and conditional formatting if at all possible, but it IS a (time-consuming and costly) possibility for about half of it if that is the only way to speed it up.

Is there anything else that I can do to make the code run faster, or is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Code changed to reflect comments/suggestions as of 2/21. Similar results.

Comment: You're missing one of the big three application environment settings. Turn off event handling with Application.EnableEvents = False. Turn it back on before leaving the sub.

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overflow!***  ...can you elaborate a bit on `my VBA scripts won't run`?  Have you tried stepping through the code to determine which line is the issue?  Sounds like an interesting issue *(from where I'm sitting, anyway!* :-)  Could you [edit] explain more about what you're trying to do, why, and what's happening? Also, check out "[mcve]", and there's also some [great tips here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Jeeped I knew I had forgotten one! I didn't remember offhand which one it was, and didn't get around to looking it up. It didn't help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet
    .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = False
End With
```

This disables the conditional formatting that is causing the slowdown. It should be reenabled after the code is run.

thanks again, @sktneer. Your help pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome Egaeus! Glad your issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs instantly with Excel 2013.

Though the code can be written as below...

```
Sub ClearFormattingAndValidation()
Dim referenceCell As Range
Dim rngToFormat As Range

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Set referenceCell = Cells.Find("Some specific text", after:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not referenceCell Is Nothing Then
    Set rngToFormat = Range(referenceCell.Offset(2, 0), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    With rngToFormat
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .Validation.Delete
    End With
End If

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It ran pretty much instantly on a smaller version of my worksheet. It's strange.

As far as your edits, I really need to internalize working with the objects directly, don't I? Old habits die hard....

Comment: @Egaeus I guess you *avoided* select but couldn't get enough of activate. :). So instead of working already on the target object, you took an extra step of activating it first. Effect won't really matter on small scale applications but that extra step will pile up on larger scales. What you can do next time is to step through each line of code and check how long it runs. You can make use of `Time` function for that. Run your code line by line using `F8` and add break points on parts of our code you want to analyze.

Comment: @L42, Yeah, I knew someone would mention that Activate. I was having trouble working through how to select the target, and knew that activating a single cell once would have little effect. 

I know the problem line. It's the .Delete of the FormatConditions. That's where it stops responding. It will eventually complete if I leave it overnight.

I changed the code to better match sktneer's suggestion. I also tried deleting the validation before the conditional formatting, just so that it would reduce the amount of "stuff" that Excel has to deal with. It didn't help. It still sticks there.

Comment: Using Time(), and waiting patiently, I found that it took 7 minutes and 13 seconds to delete the conditional formatting in the large worksheet.

Comment: How large your data is?

Comment: @sktneer There are about 76,300 cells selected.

Comment: I just created some dummy data (150000 cells), inserted a data validation list for all of them, applied a conditional formatting to all the cells and then tested the code. The code ran instantly.

Comment: @sktneer, That was helpful, thank you. Going on what you posted, I did some more experimenting. I've determined that the problem seems to be formula-based conditional formatting. If I delete the formatting on the left half of the sheet (Cols A-Z), runtime is reduced to ~4 minutes. On the right side (Cols AA-AO, but more involved), the runtime is ~3 minutes. If I remove all formula-based conditions, which represents 35 of 60 total conditions on 2 rows (31 total cells), the runtime is <1 second.

Comment: Sorry, that's 68 total cells. I missed my edit window on that.

Comment: Can you share your file if it doesn't contain any private information? Upload the file to the DropBox or Google Drive and share a link if possible.

Comment: @sktneer That's unfortunately not possible. I would get fired for sure. :)

Comment: I definitely don't want that. :)

Comment: @sktneer I know, right? In attempting to speed up the formula-based conditional formatting (e.g. using `VLOOKUP()` instead of nested `IF()` statements) I have discovered that, years ago, I was an idiot. I found multiple examples of redundant statements, in the form of `=IF(AND()),1,0)`, when it should have simply been `=AND()`. Wow. I don't know what to say about myself 4 years ago.... We'll see if improving the condition formulas speeds up processing.

Comment: Negligible improvement.